# css -webkit-linear-gradient animation

Tags: css

I have stumbled upon a problem where linear-gradient keyframes animation does not want to work for chrome and Mozilla but works for IE. 
What happens is: at the beginning of the animation, gradient is shown at the from{position and then jumps right to to{position without smooth move like it does on IE.
I think it ignores the animation, because the jump from{ to to{ happens within 1.0sec regardless on how many seconds I place in animation duration option, IE recognizes these changes.
Tried using percentages, tried placing all under one keyframe, nothing worked.
Other animations like scale and opacity work on all browsers.

Please advise!

```
#topBody{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #696969, 0px -3px 10px #696969;
    animation: anim1 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim1 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: anim1 3s ease-out;
}

@keyframes anim1{
    from{
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 1%, black 1%);
    }
    to{
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim1{
    from{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 1%, black 1%);
    }
    to{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes anim1{
    from{
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0%, ghostwhite 1%, black 1%);
    }
    to{
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 80%, ghostwhite 85%, black 85%);
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot animate gradient like this

Comment: the duplcate deals with transition but the same logic apply to animation

Comment: Yea. I guess only IE supports this approach. I think it can be done with javascript. Will try and post my result.

Comment: no need JS, play with background-size/position instead

Comment: I tried to figure out your suggestion, after 2 min gave up and wrote javascript which works nice with window.onload.